# IntelliJ: Set source compatability version plus make suggestions no longer suggest unsupported features

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the SE JDK `1.8.0_45` installed on my computer. I want both source and target versions of the compiler to be 1.7.

I did so successfully in gradle, but I cannot figure out how to do that in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3 (Community Edition).

I want the IDE to give out errors when 1.8 features are used and I also do not want it to suggest my anything 1.8.

When I use 1.8 features (ex. a lambda expression) and then run gradle (which is set up properly as already mentioned) then the compile step will error, saying that it does not support what I typed, but the IDE is not giving me any error output before, which is what I want to achieve.

Comment: AFAIK, The Java 1.8 compiler will not prevent you from using features which were only added in 1.8.  I suggest you use the Java 7 JDK if you need to run on this platform.

Comment: You can change the language level as answered by Divers, however, if you are restricted to use 1.7, I strongly suggest you to also change the JDK, if you leave it you could still use the new API in 1.8 (like `java.time.*`) and IntelliJ won't complain about it, and later you could have misterious problems like `MethodNotFoundError` or the like in production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your project, press CMD+ENTER -> PROJECT -> PROJECT SDK (pick your SDK, e.g. 1.8) and PROJECT LANGUAGE LEVEL (change it to level 7).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does this prevent the use of APIs added since Java 7?

Comment: I've got your idea, but you need to add an explanation (edit JDK for it to "point" to a 1.7 version, etc) maybe it is obvious for you, but for people who has never seen that screen the picture itself doesn't explain anything

Comment: @PeterLawrey - by not knowing new APIs in java8 :)